# Why does Google Maps container load as a grey blank all of a sudden in this setup?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Can anyone spot the error below ? It was working fine for me until I made some minor change apparently, and now the area where the map is supposed to show is a grey blank. A style also appears to be applied to my `#big-map` container which I don't think was there before when my code was working (but then again I might be wrong) Anyway, it's been driving me crazy, I think I've been looking at this for too long on my own so I thought I would share. :-)

Thank you in advance for any help!

HTML :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="big-map"></div>
```

CSS/LESS :

```
#big-map {
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   height: 290px;
   margin-top: 20px;

   >div {
      position: absolute;
      left: -3px !important;
      top: -44px !important;
      width: 103% !important;
      height: 120% !important;
    }
}
```

Javascript/jQuery :

```
var maps = {
    addBigMap : function (options)
    {
        // build map
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var hue = options.hue ? options.hue : "#90cef1";          
        var settings = {
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
            styles : [{         
                         stylers: [{hue: hue}, {saturation: -20}],
                      },
                      {
                         featureType: "road",
                         elementType: "geometry",
                         stylers: [{lightness: 100}, {visibility: "simplified"}]
                      },
                      {
                         featureType: "road",
                         elementType: "labels",
                         stylers: [{visibility: "off"}]
                      }]
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(options.$container[0], settings);
        map.setTilt(45);
    }
};

maps.addBigMap({
    $container: $("#big-map"),
    hue: "#90cef1"
});
```

DOM Result :

```
<div id="big-map" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);">
   <div class="gm-style" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;">
      <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0; cursor: url(http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur) 8 8, default;">
         <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1; width: 100%; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
            <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 100; width: 100%;">
               <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0;">
                  <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1;"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 101; width: 100%;"></div>
            <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 102; width: 100%;"></div>
            <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 103; width: 100%;"></div>
            <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 0;">
               <div style="overflow: hidden;"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 2; width: 100%; height: 100%;">         </div>
         <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 3; width: 100%; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
            <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 104; width: 100%;"></div>
            <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 105; width: 100%;"></div>
            <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 106; width: 100%;"></div>
            <div style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 107; width: 100%;"></div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your `stylers: [{hue: hue}, {saturation: -20}],` line in your js you've got an extra comma at the end.

Comment: Thanks for that! Unfortunately this didn't fix it.I so wish it had though :)

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-K (Firefox) or Ctrl-Shift-I (Chrome) and look at the JS console.  Any errors?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed I have multiple stylers.. This doesn't look normal.. I think I might have pasted my new code and kept the old code as well. I'll try removing the duplicates

Comment: nope no erroes I'm afraid

Comment: Are you checking whether the maps js has finished loading before firing `maps.addBigMap`?  Maybe you should add a `callback=maps.init` to the external script source's querystring, then in your `maps` object add `init: function() { maps.addBigMap(opts) }`.  Get rid of `sensor=false` while you're at it.  That's no longer needed (although it isn't the source of the problem).

Comment: The script is currently loading synchronously apparently because I'm not getting any errors, the Google API is there when I start using it. Adding `callback=fn` actually makes it asynchronous apparently and only then do I get undefined errors.

Comment: In your `var map = new google.maps.Map(options.$container[0], settings);` line, you're calling $container as an array.  Is it?  Try removing the `[0]`.

Comment: `options.$container` returns an array (that's what jQuery selectors always return - even if only one element is found). Otherwise the code would break. The selector works fine otherwise my container wouldn't get populated to begin with.

Comment: I got it.  In your settings object, add center and zoom and remove mapTypeId.  Apparently those are not optional when constructing a `new google.maps.Map`.  I played around with it for a while in jsfiddle, and as soon as I added those two options and took out `mapTypeId` the map loaded.  Part of the problem I think is that mapTypeId of ROADMAP should be a constant rather than a string.  If this works for you I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: You're right, I was about to post that as an answer! Be my guest.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `center` and `zoom` options don't have default values in the `new google.maps.Map` constructor.  Also, `mapTypeId` takes a [constant as an argument](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeId), rather than a string.

Therefore, to fix this, add default values for `center` and `zoom`, and get rid of `mapTypeId` (as Google defaults the type to ROADMAP anyway).

Finally, remove the trailing comma at the end of the first `stylers` line.

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ksnxot0/) to play with if you wish.

```js
maps = {
    addBigMap: function(options) {
        // build map
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var hue = options.hue ? options.hue : "#90cef1";     
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(36.4120739, -82.444035);
        var settings = {
            center: latlng,
            zoom: 8,
            styles : [{         
                         stylers: [{hue: hue}, {saturation: -20}]
                      },
                      {
                         featureType: "road",
                         elementType: "geometry",
                         stylers: [{lightness: 100}, {visibility: "simplified"}]
                      },
                      {
                         featureType: "road",
                         elementType: "labels",
                         stylers: [{visibility: "off"}]
                      }]
        };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(options.$container[0], settings);
        map.setTilt(45);
    },
    init: function() {
        if (document.readyState === 'loading') {
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', maps.init);
            return;
        }
        maps.addBigMap({
            $container: $("#big-map"),
            hue: "#90cef1"
        });
    }
};
```

```css
#big-map {
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   height: 290px;
   margin-top: 20px;

   >div {
      position: absolute;
      left: -3px !important;
      top: -44px !important;
      width: 103% !important;
      height: 120% !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=maps.init"></script>
<div id="big-map"></div>
```